# SSIS Error DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

As in the pictorial details, there is a foreach loop container in SSIS package for importing data from all excel files reside in "C\Source\Files".  Theoretically, the value of variable 'FileName' is assigned in each loop and will be used in Excel Connection Manager to extract data. But for creating the components, during design phase, we have to set the variable value to a sample excel file having same template/columns as others. If variable value is not assigned, it will throw error "SSIS Error DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER". The files in "C\Source\Files" are placed randomly and will be immediately archived after data import, so there can be situations where no files present in the folder. Is there any way to avoid the intial binding as it will cost extra to keep sample files in environments UAT/PROD?

- The package components and properties

[image]

- Error when variable values is empty ("")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jithin,

You could try disabling/delaying the validation until runtime.

In the package or component properties, set the DelayValidation property to True (it defaults to False). Setting to true will effectively not perform validation until you execute the package.

You mileage may vary with respect to Excel, which can be particularly difficult to work with in SSIS for a variety of reasons, but give this a go.